# Using && in if () operator

Tags: javascript

A friend of mine wrote me some code (and unfortunately he's un accessible right now) and I'm trying to understand it.

```
const people = [
  {name: 'morgan', group: 3},
  {name: 'courtney', group: 1},
  {name: 'brian', group: 1},
  {name: 'dog', group: 2}
]

const partitionedPeople = sortedPeople.reduce(
  (parts, person) => {    
    const part = parts[0]

    if (part && person.group === part.group) {
      console.log('found part.group')
    } else {
      console.log('did not find part.group')
    }
    return parts;
  },
  []
);
```

What I don't understand is `if (part && person.group === part.group) {}`

If I change it to `if (person.group === part.group) {}` I get an error.

Because through the first iteration, `part` is undefined (first item in an empty list) and I'm asking it to find `.group` of undefined, which makes sense.

However, when adding in `(part && person.group === part.group)` it works just fine.

What is `part && person.group` doing so that the function works?

Comment: Not a very practical usage of `reduce()`

Comment: thanks for your valuable input! @charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement can be rewritten like this:

```
if (part) {
  if (person.group === part.group) {
    //...
  }
}
```

The part before the `&&` checks to make sure `part` exists (not `undefined`, or `null`, or `0`, etc.)

The part after the `&&` checks for equality between `person.group` and `part.group`

Comment: OH! Hah, did not know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `&&` operator works like this:

- if the first operand is **truthy**, it returns the **second** operand
- if the first operand is **falsy**, it returns the **first** operand

Here, if `part` is `undefined` (which is falsy), the expression evaluates to `undefined` (because the first operand is returned). `undefined` is falsy, so the `if` body is not executed.

If `part` is defined and truthy, then *and only then* does `&&` evaluate the second operand, which compares `person.group` with `part.group` and returns the result of the comparison.

In JavaScript, everything is truthy except for `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of left expression of `&&` is falsy, it returns the value of left expression, otherwise it returns the value of right expression.

So, when `part` is `undefined`, `(part && person.group === part.group)` returns `part` (which is `undefined`) immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because `part` does not have a property called `group` probably because `part` is itself not defined.

Using `&&` ensures that the second condition after the `&&` will only be processed/evaluated only if the first condition `part` is true.

So by putting `part` first it will evaluate `person.group === part.group` only if `part` is true. And as I already said by removing `part` you are then allowing the code to evaluate the second condition that has `part.group` and whenever you try to access a property (`.group`) from an undefined object then an Uncaught TypeError will result.

I would assume your error looks something like this:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined`